# Angular JS Filter binding and NULL results

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have bound my select filter and ng-repeat successfully, but am struggling to 'remove' the filter when then user selects the default (null) value as this is actually matching some results.

The data is structured as such;

**Filter**

Select input:

```
<select name="category" id="category" ng-model="category" ng-options="category.name as category.name for category in categories">
    <option value="" label="Select a category">Select a category</option>
</select>
```

Data set

```
categories [
    0: {
        name: "Category name"
        products: [
            0: "product name"
            ...  
        ]
    }
    ...
]
```

**ng-repeat**

Repeating element:

```
<li ng-repeat="store in stores | filter: category as products">
    <h3>{[{ store.name }]}</h3>
</li>
```

Data set:

```
stores: [
    0: {
        ...
        name: "Store name"
        products: [
            0: {
                name: "Category name"
                products: [
                    0: "Product name"
                    ...
                ]
            }
            ...
        ]
        ...
    }
    1: {
        ...
        name: "Store 2"
        products: null
    }
    ...
]
```

It's worth noting that the above data set is in it's correct format, with products instead of categories (i will attempt to have this changed at some point in the future!)

As it is, the filter works, probably exactly as i am telling it to. The problem is when the "Select category" default value is selected, the stores that have a null value for products are the only items shown. It's at that point that i want All items shown or a "clear" on the filter.

Comment: can you please pest here your code snippet?

Comment: What code snippet, Jigar?

Comment: A one working demo of your above's code?, as i am working on it to provide you answer i will need it

Comment: Thanks Jigar, but as i am sure you can imagine, this is part of a much larger angular application. If you think you need it, i can work up a comparable working version?

Comment: No thanks, let me to figured it out on my own, will let you know

Comment: I have asked you because i don't know how kind of json or array you are using for categories and stores as input, can you please provide me?

Comment: Both the data set's are demonstrated in the above code. The format is identical for both sets (but with more values where the '...' appears) Does this help?